# News page layout with SharePoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I want to create News page layout with SharePoint Designer but I found solutions with Visual Studio. Is there any step by step guide to do that?

Visual Studio step by step guidance link:
https://startsharepoint.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/step-by-step-creating-news-page-layout-using-content-type-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Find it here-> https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146848/How-to-create-a-SharePoint-Publishing-Page-Layout

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create Page Layouts in SharePoint you can create it through Design Manager by URL -->_layouts/15/DesignWelcomePage.aspx.

Click on 6. Edit Page Layouts.  Click on Create a Page Layout.  Give your page layout a name, pick your master page and your content type.

[You can refer here how to create pagelayout](http://blog.navantis.com/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2013/)